# Bash: echo & copy result

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm just trying to make a function that echos and copies whatever is passed to it to the clipboard:

```
function c() {
  echo "$@"
  pbcopy "$@"
}
```

`c 123` echos properly but then just waits for input
`pwd | c` copies to the clipboard but doesn't echo

Comment: Do you want to echo&copy positional parameters or input from stdin?

Comment: @oguzismail Both, apparently.

Comment: Ok, but it's not **apparent** without example input and output.

Comment: My answer covers positional parameters since that was what was being used in the OP. If stdin is also desired, somebody else can figure that one out.

Comment: @oguzismail It's just what I guessed based on the two examples, not meaning to imply "obviously, duh" or something.

Comment: Such a function should take exactly *one* argument, the exact string you want copied to the clipboard, not a series of separate arguments that get joined together in an ad-hoc fashion.

Comment: @chepner I think OP is looking to replicate the behavior of echo, which takes n arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands

```
function c() {
  echo "$@" | tee >(pbcopy)
}
```

Should do the trick. I tested this in zsh, but i expect this will work in bash as well.

As that other guy pointed out in the comments, pbcopy reads from stdin, it doesn't copy arguments, which is why your pipe vs argument test had the results it did.

`tee` splits the pipe, sending stdout to a file, but also leaves it in stdout.

`>(command)` opens a file descriptor which pipes to `command`

Combining the two allows us to echo the arguments back to stdout while also piping them to `pbcopy`

A caveat to this solution is that the clipboard will contain a newline, as echo by default adds a newline to output. This could be prevented by passing the `-n` flag to echo.

Comment: In other words, `pbcopy` reads from stdin so you'd have to do `echo "$@" | pbcopy` instead of `pbcopy "$@"`. Or merge them like this.

Comment: `c 123` works perfectly, but the `pwd | c` case doesn't echo or copy unfortunately

Comment: no, it wouldn't, since "$@" picks up arguments to c, not what has been piped to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that checks if arguments are supplied and reads input from stdin if not:

```
c() {
    if (( $# )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$*"
        printf '%s' "$*" | pbcopy
    else
        tee >(pbcopy)
    fi
    return 0
}
```

The somewhat cumbersome double `printf` is there to avoid getting the linebreak into the clipboard. For the case of reading from stdin, however, you will have that linebreak in the clipboard if you feed it one:

```
$ c blah
blah
$ pbpaste
blah$ echo blah | c
blah
$ pbpaste
blah
$ printf blah | c
blah$ pbpaste
blah$
```

where the `$` is the command prompt, directly behind the output if the output doesn't contain a newline. This might or might not be what you want: I find that I expect the newline to not be in the string if I supply the string as an argument, and if I read from standard input, I'll leave the newline there if there is one.